# how to automate the angular 10 _ grid using filters and check the grid is displayed based on filter in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how to automate the angular 10 _ grid using filters and check the grid is displayed based on filter in selenium c#
[image: Kindly check the below image]

> try
> {
> Exceloperations.PopulateInCollection(@"D:\Grid.xlsx");
> for (int i = 1; i <= Exceloperations.GetTotalRowCount(); i++)
> {
>
> ```
>                     ReadExcel(Driver.driver, i);                    
>
>                 }
>             }
>             catch (Exception e)
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine(e.Message);                
>             
>             }
> ```

// Getting elements from the excel

```
public void ReadExcel(IWebDriver driver, int rowNum)
        {
            Menus menu = new Menus();
            Invoices_obj invoices_Obj = new Invoices_obj();

            try
            {
                if(invoices_Obj.Grid_Filter.Enabled)
                {
                                        invoices_Obj.Grid_Filter.Click();
                   
                                   }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Already filter is enable"); 
                }
                
                invoices_Obj.hourscolumn_Gridfilter.Click();
                
                Console.WriteLine("-------------- Hours column Equals ------------------");

                invoices_Obj.hourscolumn_dd_Field_dd.Click();              

                invoices_Obj.hourscolumn_dd_Field_dd_value_equals.Click();               

                string Totalhourseq = Exceloperations.ReadData(rowNum, "Hours_Customequals");
               // Console.WriteLine(rowNum);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);               


                if (rowNum != null)

                {
                   
                    Actions actions = new Actions(Driver.driver);                              
                
                    invoices_Obj.hourscolumn_dd_input.SendKeys(Totalhourseq);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("input value as "+ Totalhourseq);

                    invoices_Obj.Gridcolumn_Apply.Click();
                   
}
}
```

Comment: Show your effort so far, please.

Comment: What have you tried so far?